# Sticky button with ScrollView doesn't show full list

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to have a list and then a button, but if I try to have a button and then a list like so:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Button} onPress={() => this.props.navigate(1)}>
                {buttonText}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
            </View>
            <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
            </View>
            <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
```

You see that green isn't being fully shown:

[image]

This doesn't happen if the button isn't there.

And if I move

```
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Button} onPress={() => this.props.navigate(1)}>
                {buttonText}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

to be after the ScrollView, I don't see the button.

So to sum it up, I want the button to be stickied to the bottom while having every element in the scroll view to be fully shown. How can it be done?

This is the style of the button BTW:

```
Button: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 5,
    margin: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#4267b2',
    borderColor: '#ffffff',
    alignItems: 'center'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he proper way to achieve this is by using flex

this is an example for 1 : 10 flex body to header ratio

```
 render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
    <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
      <ScrollView >
        <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        </View>
        <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
        </View>
        <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
      <Button style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', alignSelf:'center' }}
        title="THIS IS A BUTTON" />
    </View>
  </View>
   );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
   headerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  bodyContainer: {
    flex: 10
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted the button to be after the scroll view. If I move it to be after, I don't see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can stick your button view with a `position: absolute`, set its height and add a margin-bottom of this height on the scrollview.

**Render**

```
return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.list}>
            <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
            </View>
            <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
            </View>
            <View style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.fixedBottom}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Button} onPress={() => this.props.navigate(1)}>
                {buttonText}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

**Style**

```
...
fixedBottom: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    height: 50, // <== the height on your view containing the button
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  },
list: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 50, // <== here the margin to see the full list
},
...
```

[Here is a live demo](https://snack.expo.io/B1BCEgqY-).

Comment: @kuhaku just add `flex: 1` on your list container. I updated my answer for this case